# jquery ajax call -- alternative to using session?

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services, session

I was asked not to use `Session` anywhere in my code. Currently, I'm authenticating the user to the web services interface and storing the access token (an object) in session and re-using it for subsequent requests. What would be a good place to store it on server-side? I don't want to send it to the client for security reasons.

Here's the code -

```
 var person;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Default.aspx/LoadPerson',
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: 1 }),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            person = result.d;
        }
    });
```

My Web service method looks something like this -

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static Person LoadPerson(int i)
    {
        var person = new Person();
        person.Name = "Bob";
        var userToken = SetupWebserviceUser();
        HttpContext.Current.Session["UserToken"] = userToken();
        // Call web service, get data.
        return person;
    }
```

Comment: Why can't you use the session? This seems like the perfect place to store this data. The other option would be store the token in a database or in memory on the server and keep track of the user with a cookie, but that is exactly how the session works in .net...

Comment: The app is going to be integrated into a Sharepoint site on a web farm. Our admin asked me to avoid using session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would be a good place to store it on server-side?

There aren't too many options left, if you do not want to store the data in the client or in the seesion.
The only options that I can think of is a DataBase\static variable\ XML file.

Comment: Will it persist the data across calls if I put it in a static variable? Edit: It does! I just needed three properties off of the access token object. I've created three static variables, set the value and was able to access it in subsequent calls. Now, how do I dispose this data?

Comment: Static can be potentially dangerous, remember that web access is multi-threaded and verify that you can't access this as another user who shouldn't be allowed while the first user is still active.

Comment: I have a global load function which gets called only once when the page loads. I've explicitly set the variables to null at the beginning of that function. Working fine now. Thanks!

Comment: @enigma. No problems. just make sure to use `lock` if there are multi-threaded threats.